# Java newbie trying to concatenate 3 choiceboxes into one String

Tags: java, javafx-8

Java newbie at the end of my second java class and I've put together my final project in which I chose to use 3 choice box's  to allow the user to select month, day and year.  I don't know how to concatenate them into a single String for birthdate.  I felt this was the correct choice for date selection

Comment: You should provide some more data, like related parts of source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the three values from the choiceboxes:

```
String monthString = monthChoiceBox.getValue() // e.g. "12"
String dayString = dayChoiceBox.getValue() // e.g. "01"
String yearString = yearChoiceBox.getValue() // e.g. "2015"
```

And then concatenate them all together to get your string (below is separated by slashes in MM/DD/YYYY format):

```
String date = monthString + "/" + dayString + "/" + yearString // "12/01/2015"
```

Comment: Thanks. I got in this morning and realized two things. One I was not using the correct syntax to .getValue() of the choice and second was creating the String (once it worked) out of scope. So thanks this helped  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = Combobox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + Combobox2.getSelectedItem().toString() + Combobox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Else if its `CheckBox`, use:

`String x = CheckBox1.getItem() + CheckBox2.getItem() + CheckBox3.getItem();`

**EDIT:**

Sorry for misinterpretation. I'll just add this to my answer and leave it as.

`String x = ChoiceBox1.getValue() + ChoiceBox2.getValue() + ChoiceBox3.getValue();`

Comment: And next time, give a reason when you downvote.

Comment: Presumably by `ChoiceBox`, the OP meant [`ChoiceBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) (I didn't downvote, though it's probably justified...)

Comment: Thanks. I got in this morning and realized two things. One I was not using the correct syntax to .getValue() of the choice and second was creating the String (once it worked) out of scope. So thanks this helped  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your checkboxes are named as below

```
String dob = checkBox1.getText() + checkBox2.getText() + checkBox3.getText();
```

you may want to consider using a Date Picker
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm